# Replacement for CMake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I'm using CMake into build rules in visual studio to preprocess my files before submitting them to the compiler but my customers don't like it.

Is there any CMake alternative or method to preprocess my files and having them integrated into visual studio?

Comment: I dont quite get the idea, why customers dont like the idea of cmake. It creates you the platform dependant files ( make/sln/.project ) but allows you to write it down platform independant. So I would not care much about that question, because the answer is most likely to be platform dependant ( aka offering them only the visual studio sln )

Comment: I would explain to your customers the benefits to using cmake over what visual studio alone offers. And that these benefits outweigh the cost of the additional steps of learning how to use CMake and creating a CMakeLists.txt file per target.

Comment: Why not just ship the CMake-generated files to your customers?  That way they don't have to use CMake, but you can.

Comment: I don't know this specific case, but the usability difference between a hand-maintained Visual Studio project (or Xcode project) and an auto-generated one can be quite large.

Comment: @JohnZwinck. Because the CMake-generated files very likely use fixed absolute paths to 3rd-party libraries and won't work on the client's development machine. In addition, the CMake-generated files still require CMake.

Comment: I'm voting to close this old question because I think it needs/needed details/clarity: What exactly is CMake being used to do? Why don't the customers like it? How are the pre-processed files currently being integrated into visual studio? On top of that, what it's asking for (alternatives) is too open ended. The requirements haven't been stated clearly enough.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand the question you are using CMake to generate files consumed by a VS project that you created by hand.  For whatever reason your customers of your VS project don't like CMake.  Presumably you have wired this up by creating custom build steps that invoke CMake to generate the files in your project, either as Build Events on the project, or as custom build steps on various files in the project, such as the inputs to the scripts.

VS lets you run any arbitrary set of commands as part of a Build Event or a Custom Build Step.  So you could replace CMake with a suitable script or custom executable written by yourself.  It is hard to be specific without knowing exactly what about CMake isn't appealing to your customers.

You can use JavaScript through Windows Script Host to create fairly complex scripts that process custom build steps.  They can take command-line arguments, access the file system, etc.  For some reason WSH JavaScript is a big secret among most developers and they think that all they have available to them in Windows out-of-the-box are DOS batch files and power shell scripts.  JavaScript has been shipping for over 10 years as part of the OS and you can debug the scripts in Visual Studio's script debugger, which is very nice.